# Auth is not working in middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-7, laravel-authentication

I have successfully loggedin my adminpanel but while I redirect to dashboard after login using middleware it's not working.

**login controller**

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
{
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

**route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['adminAuth']], function () {

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'dashboardController@index');

});
```

**dashboard controller**

```
public function index()
{
    return 'admin dashboard';
}
```

**adminAuthenticate.php Middleware**

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_code == '1'){
        return $next($request);                
    }    
    return abort(404);
}
```

**kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'adminAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\adminAuthenticate::class,
    ];
```

Always it returns '404' page though I have successfully loggedin.

Where is the problem ? anybody help please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: check your role_code. is user  role == 1 or not

Comment: @sokhai...   user_role is 1....all are ok

Comment: have you try dd() in handle() method. to check it work or not

Comment: @sokhai...I have succesfully loggedin in loginController. And I checked there.

Comment: Is your `adminAuth` middleware registered in the kernel?

Comment: @ArafatRahman provide your kernel code also.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter...yess I have registered...I have updated the post with kernel.php

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?